# react-native navigation v2 - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm trying to use react-navigation v2. This is how my App component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import FirstScreen './firstscreen';
import SecondScreen './secondscreen';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    FirstScreen: { screen: FirstScreen },
    SecondScreen: { screen: SecondScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FirstScreen',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    )
  }
}
```

Executing this results in this Error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I found some examples where StackNavigator is used like this, maybe I'm missing something. In the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) it seems the same.

But if I do this it actually works fine.

```
export default AppNavigator;
```

I want to change it because I'm trying to pass a MobX store.

Did someone run into this issue before?
Thank you guys in advance.

---

Edit1: *What I found out: only occurs on Android devices, react-native run-ios is working fine.*

---

**SOLVED**
We were using this [Symbol npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-symbol) to support [JS Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). That caused the error. Removing this package solved the problem.

Comment: have you `import FirstScreen ./from/your/path/Firstscreen` ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda yes but I didn't add it to the code.. sorry

Comment: Check my answer below as react navigation is working fine in my app.

Answer (score 0):

if you forget to import file then add it to the above of your constant like,

```
import FirstScreen ./from/your/path/Firstscreen
```

But as of your `export default AppNavigator;` is working fine so may be there is any other changes you have to do in your firstscreen file.

Check export class of your firstscreen file like below.

```
export default class Firstscreen extends React.Component {}
```